# '@angular/Material' Components Not Working. Showing errors in IDE

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing a weird issue within my project. I opened up my project one day only to find my HTML files filled with errors. Some examples are:

- 'mat-menu' is not a known element
- 'mat-tab-group' is not a known element
- And more confusingly, < router-outlet > is not a known element

Basically, all my '@angular/material' components are shown to be non-existent and aren't known within the project. Operations such as ngFor and ngIf also show errors such as:

- Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ng
- Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ng

I know my ngFor and ngIf statements are working properly because before these errors occurred, there were no issues.

However, when I use 'ng serve' and open up Chrome, the application runs, and all material components operate as they should. It only shows up as having errors within my VSCode IDE, and doesn't interfere with building the app.

I imported the material components via 'shared/material.module' and 'shared/shared.module'. I can say for certain that all my module and routing files are working properly with the proper imports and exports because I have not touched them during my last edit, which was error-free.

Why and how could this be happening?

Comment: See the [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started): you need add the @angular/material package, import the BrowserModule and the angular material module you need in your app.module (really in the module where your component that use the material component are defined) futhermore import in your styles.css some of the themes, e.g. in your styles.css: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: @Eliseo - As I said, I have those imported already, I have a `material.module` with all `@angular/material` imports, and a shared.module that contains said material.module. Every module, including app.module, has an import of the shared module and material module. I also checked my styles.css file and it contains an import of purple-green.css

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your IDE issue. You have to explore through the source files (Angular Core, Material modules) in `node_modules` folder. And then IDE should show you properly view for this attributes.

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer with this? What would I look for in `node_modules`? I had a feeling this was an IDE issue, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This worked for me.
You need to run this cmd in the project folder and then close VS code and open again with the project folder